# Черная сфера у компонента при выборе

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

При выборе компонента unity появляется черная сфера. Как её отключить?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в объекте Probes. Попробуй удалить его или отключить. Если не получится попробуй перезапустить Unity или нажать **Window > Layouts > Reset All Layouts**